# Javascript Delete Button does not work in editorjs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a mini-blog app, and I am trying to make a button to delete posts, but It doesn't work. It doesn't show any errors. I am confused. What I should do ? How can I tell what's going on to see where is the issue ? I have seen many relevant posts but it doesn't seems to be helpful for my situation.

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- style file -->
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <!-- editorjs adn -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/editorjs@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/header@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/list@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/checklist@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/quote@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/code@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/table@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@editorjs/embed@latest"></script>
    
    <!-- CSS --> 
    <style>
    body {
        margin: auto;
        max-width: 900px;
    }
    #editor {
    
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    .inserted_time {
        font-style: italic;
        font-size: 8px;
        text-align: right;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<h2>Create a Blog</h2>
<button onclick="toggleBlogForm()" id="switchbutton">Create Post</button>

<div id="allblogs"></div>
<div id="editor"></div>
<div id="conversion"></div>


<button id="post_to_blog">Submit</button>


<div id="message"></div>


<script>

function toggleBlogForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("switchbutton");
    if (x.innerHTML == "Create Post") {
        x.innerHTML = "View Post";
        document.getElementById("allblogs").style.visibility = "hidden";
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Create Post";

    }
}


// saved posts
const blogs = [{"time":1641955404060,"blocks":[{"id":"t_39IX2iIH","type":"header","data":{"text":"First Blog Post","level":2}},{"id":"jBunZLMaJC","type":"paragraph","data":{"text":"gogogo"}}],"version":"2.22.2"},{"time":1641955680472,"blocks":[{"id":"fbfQo5o1_y","type":"list","data":{"style":"ordered","items":["ABC","DEF","HIJ"]}}],"version":"2.22.2"},{"time":1641955749893,"blocks":[{"id":"idQrTDXnzJ","type":"checklist","data":{"items":[{"text":"English","checked":true},{"text":"French","checked":false},{"text":"German","checked":false}]}}],"version":"2.22.2"},{"time":1641957539439,"blocks":[{"id":"ztUBHu3HHg","type":"table","data":{"withHeadings":false,"content":[["Category","Language"],["1","Java"],["2","Python"]]}}],"version":"2.22.2"},{"time":1641959106166,"blocks":[{"id":"Q6Z-TKWLup","type":"embed","data":{"service":"youtube","source":"https://youtu.be/tbXpX4dAqjg","embed":"https://www.youtube.com/embed/tbXpX4dAqjg","width":580,"height":320,"caption":"This is a tutorial for learning PHP Symfony framework."}}],"version":"2.22.2"}]
    
const blog_inserted_time = ["11:43:24 12/1/2022", "11:43:24 12/1/2022", "11:43:24 12/1/2022", "12:18:59 12/1/2022", "12:45:6 12/1/2022"]
    
// retrieve posts when loading the page
console.log(blogs.length);
loadingPosts();
console.log('retrieved!')




// constructor for the blog
const editor = new EditorJS({
  
    holder: 'editor',
    
        tools: {
            header: Header,        
            list: List,        
            checklist: Checklist,
            quote: Quote,
            code: CodeTool,
            table: Table,
 
            embed: {
                class: Embed,
                inlineToolbar: true,
                config: {
                    services: {
                        youtube: true,
                        coub: true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   
});
    
    
// saving the new post
let saveBtn = document.getElementById('post_to_blog');
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    editor.save().then((outputData) => {
        
        // save to local variable
        const jsondata = outputData;
        blogs.push(jsondata);
        console.log(blogs);
  
    
        // get and save time
        var currentdate = new Date(); 
        var datetime =  currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                    + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                    + currentdate.getSeconds() + " "
                    + currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                    + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                    + currentdate.getFullYear();
        blog_inserted_time.push(datetime);
        console.log("inserted time: " + currentdate);
        
            
    
        // reload all posts
        var divForReset = document.getElementById('allblogs');
        while(divForReset.firstChild){
            divForReset.removeChild(divForReset.firstChild);
        }
        loadingPosts();
            
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Failed: ', error)
        });
            
});
    
    
    
function loadingPosts() {
    
    for(var i = 0; i < blogs.length; i++) {
                
                
            var getBlocks = blogs[i]['blocks'];
            //console.log('retrieving');
            //console.log(getBlocks);
    
            for(var y = 0; y < getBlocks.length; y++) {
                console.log('printing text.......');
                console.log(getBlocks[y]);
                var msg = convertDataToHtml(getBlocks);
                console.log(msg);
            }
    
            // create a div for a post
            var addblog = document.createElement('div');
   
            // get post data from json array
            var textmsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
    
            //addblog.appendChild(textmsg);
            var addblog = document.createElement('div');
    
            // deleteButton
            const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
            deleteButton.innerHTML = 'delete';
            addblog.appendChild(deleteButton);
    
            deleteButton.addEventListener('click', evt => {
                evt.preventDefault();
            　　alert('it does not work!!!');
            });
                
            // get time 
            addblog.innerHTML += "<p class='inserted_time'>"+blog_inserted_time[i]+"</p>";
            // get post
            addblog.innerHTML += msg;
            addblog.style.cssText = "border: 1px solid; padding: 10px";
            document.getElementById('allblogs').appendChild(addblog);
 
    
                
    
                
    
            msg = '';
     
        }
    
            
    
}
    
function convertDataToHtml(blocks) {
    var convertedHtml = "";
    blocks.map(block => {
         
        switch (block.type) {
            case "header":
                convertedHtml += 
`<h${block.data.level}>${block.data.text}</h${block.data.level}>`;
                break;
            case "embed":
                convertedHtml += `<div><iframe width="560" height="315" src="${block.data.embed}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>`;
                convertedHtml += `<p>${block.data.caption}</p></div>`;
                break;
            case "paragraph":
                convertedHtml += `<p>${block.data.text}</p>`;
                break;
            case "delimiter":
                convertedHtml += "<hr />";
                break;
            case "image":
                convertedHtml += `<img class="img-fluid" 
    src="${block.data.file.url}" title="${block.data.caption}" /><br /> 
    <em>${block.data.caption}</em>`;
                break;
            case "list":
                convertedHtml += "<ul>";
                block.data.items.forEach(function(li) {
                    convertedHtml += `<li>${li}</li>`;
                });
                convertedHtml += "</ul>";
                break;
            case "checklist":
                convertedHtml += "<ul>";
                block.data.items.forEach(function(li) {
                    if (li["checked"] == true) {
                        convertedHtml += `<ol>&#10003; ${li["text"]} 
</ol>`;
                    } else {
                        convertedHtml += `<ol>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
${li["text"]}</ol>`;
                    }
                });
                convertedHtml += "</ul>";
                break;
            case "table":
                convertedHtml += "<table class='table table-striped table-hover'>";
                block.data.content.forEach(function(tdata) {
                    convertedHtml += "<tr>";
                    for (a = 0; a < tdata.length; a++) {
                        convertedHtml += "<td>" + tdata[a] + "</td>";
                    }
               
                    convertedHtml += "</tr>";
                });
                convertedHtml += "</table>";
                break;
    
            case "code":
                convertedHtml += `<code>${block.data.code}</code>`;
 
    
    
            default:
                console.log("Unknown block type", block.type);
                break;
        }
    });
    return convertedHtml;
}
    
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're first appending the `deleteButton` element with the `click` event listener to the `addBlog` element and *then* using `innerHTML` to append further content to `addBlog`.

Using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML?retiredLocale=it#appending_html_to_an_element) this way will remove any previously defined event listener:

> Please note that using innerHTML to append html elements (e.g.
> el.innerHTML += "link") will result in the removal
> of any previously set event listeners. That is, after you append any
> HTML element that way you won't be able to listen to the previously
> set event listeners.

A way to solve the issue is retrieving the button and adding the event listener *after* any DOM manipulation has been completed (adding a unique `id` to any delete button will help):

```
    // create a div for a post
    const addblog = document.createElement('div');

    // deleteButton
    const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.setAttribute('id', 'deleteBtn_' + i);
    deleteButton.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    deleteButton.innerHTML = 'delete';
    addblog.appendChild(deleteButton);

    // get time
    addblog.innerHTML +=
      "<p class='inserted_time'>" + blog_inserted_time[i] + '</p>';
    // get post
    addblog.innerHTML += msg;
    addblog.style.cssText = 'border: 1px solid; padding: 10px';
    document.getElementById('allblogs').appendChild(addblog);

    // Add event listener at least
    document
      .getElementById('deleteBtn_' + i)
      .addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('it does work!!!');
      });
    msg = '';
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have one more questions.
I am trying to replace alert with deleting function.

const chosen_post = deleteButton.closest('div');
allblogs.removeChild(chosen_post);

 I am selecting div value element but error says parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: @koken Since you're handling an event it makes sense to use the `Event` interface and get a reference to the button on which the event was dispatched: `const chosen_post = evt.target.closest('div');`

Comment: Oh i see thank you . But I decided to use MVC rather than javascriot to handle it.